# PySerial: how to understand that the timeout occured while reading from serial port?

Tags: python, serial-port, timeout, pyserial

I'm using `PySerial` to read from serial port like in the code below.
`CheckReadUntil()` read output of the command that I send to serial port until the sequence of symbols `readUntil` are in the serial output.

```
...

self.ser = serial.Serial(comDev, 115200, timeout=10)

...

#Function that continue to read from Serial port until 'readUntil' 
#sequence of symbols appears
def CheckReadUntil(self, readUntil):
    outputCharacters = []
    while 1:
        ch = self.ser.read()
        outputCharacters += ch
        if outputCharacters[-len(readUntil):]==readUntil:
            break
    outputLines = ''.join(outputCharacters)
    return outputLines
```

However, if there is no sequence `readUntil` (for any reason), I'm just stuck in the function `CheckReadUntil()` forever. The setting `timeout=10` sets up timeout so I'm stuck in a loop that iterates every 10 seconds and does nothing, just waiting.

How it is possible to understand that there was a timeout event so I may exit the infinite loop? Output length may be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** (previous answer was not correct, this is the working code from @konstantin):

```
...

self.ser = serial.Serial(comDev, 115200, timeout=10)

...

#Function that continue to read from Serial port until 'readUntil' 
#sequence of symbols appears
def CheckReadUntil(self, readUntil):
    outputCharacters = []
    while 1:
        ch = self.ser.read()
        if len(ch) == 0:
            break
        outputCharacters += ch
        if outputCharacters[-len(readUntil):]==readUntil:
            break
    outputLines = ''.join(outputCharacters)
    return outputLines
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply, just checked it. There is a problem with your solution: on each read we may need to wait until timeout. For example we try to read 'abcdefg' and readUntil = 'efg'. So we read 'abc', then 'def' and then we wait for 'g' for a timeout period

Comment: What I had to do is to 'ch = self.ser.read()' + 'if len(ch) == 0:' instead of your corresponding lines. Now everything works very nice! We need to wait for timeout only when we hang up, not all the time! Thank you for the reply, again!

Comment: @Konstantin can you please explain/post your final solution after the fix, thanks

Comment: @schantischul, the essence of the problem is that serial timeout does not raise a timeout exception. A timeout is detected by checking that no characters have been returned: `if len(ch) == 0: break`. Note that a `read_until()` function is mentioned in the documentation that seems to behave like the above `CheckReadUntil()` function.